# Java: Generate Binary Search Tree from data file, Using 2d array to produce the image

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, binary-search-tree, bufferedreader

I need help creating the 2d array to produce the image for the Binary search tree.
The spacing between is not important.
I am reading the file using bufferedreader.

ex:

```
            54             
         /      \
       26       87
      /  \     /   \
    12   29   79    88
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have the node class and and BinarySearchTree methods. i.e. insert,setright,setleft...

Comment: A problem you'll encounter will be node clash - In your example 29 and 79 could occupy the same spot in your array (depending on how you implement it).  To overcome that you need to traverse your tree and work out things like width, depth, etc.

Comment: As an exercise I created a program to read a BST, then push that into a 2d array, the print it out. It's not in the same format as yours (I go right for right nodes, but _down_ for left nodes). You can see the results [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54563/print-a-non-clashing-binary-search-tree)

Comment: Also [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/849/print-a-binary-tree?lq=1)